# Slow distinct() MongoDB query on hashed index collection field

Tags: mongodb, performance, optimization, distinct

I've got a collection 55 million rows in it, and I want to be able to do `db.collection.distinct(foo)`, but that's slow.
In this case, there's only a single value for "foo" through the entire collection, so I'd expect it to be fast.

I've added an index `(foo: "hashed")`, but it's still ~30 seconds, even though there's a single value

Do I have to use a non-hashed index to get decent speed on this, or am I missing some other aspect?

Edit: I've also tried a b-tree index which doesn't improve speed at all that I can tell.

`{
        "values" : [
                "foo"
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "n" : 55316753,
                "nscanned" : 55316753,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "timems" : 14783,
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor baz_1"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}`

Comment: could you add dump from `db.collection.find({query}).explain("executionStats")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by upgrading to MongoDB 3.0 (where previously I was running 2.4.9).